# how do I prevent end-user to change values from html tags in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a lot of processes in my project that needs to be further protected.
My main Question is: how can I prevent the user to change any values of HTML tags (edit view) such as (email, mobile .. Etc.).

I'm using asp.net core[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA3n6.jpg)

Comment: You can't.  Whatever led you to think that you *need to* was a mistake.  What you *can* do is validate *in server-side code* whatever information is sent to the server.

Comment: Who said attackers use browsers to post bad data? They can easily use POSTMAN, curl, or the browser's Console and Developer Tools to create and send anything they want. Or they could use Selenium or Playwright to access your web site and execute a custom POST at the end

Comment: PS: ASP.NET Core already [supports validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and can use data annotation attributes to generate client-side validation scripts that use [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#client-side-validation) to enforce rules. For example, adding `StringLength` to a DTO property will add a check on the HTML form field *and* validate the length on the server

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately on the client side this vulnerability will exist. My advice to you is to validate that information that you think is important on the server side to avoid this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't prevent anything from happening on the client side. The source code is executed on the client so this results in complete control of the client's user.

What you can do is validate the data on the client (And again it can be manipulated by the users) and validate the information again on the server-side (API level). This will make sure that you get the correct form of data and prevent any malicious data entries.

Here are some great resources about validations:

[Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

[How to Use ModelState Validation in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-modelstate-validation-web-api/)